# Lodash Map array inside array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

```
"info": {
    "core": [{
        "name": "User",
        "fields": [{
            "field": "name",
        }, {
            "field": "age",
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Post",
        "fields": [{
            "field": "title",

        }, {
            "field": "body",
        }, {
            "field": "author",
        }]
    }]
}
```

How can I map structure data these. I want achieve something like this on web view:

1.

- name value
- fields

  - field value
  - field value

2.

- name value
- fields

  - field value
  - field value

and so on...

I tried using lodash map look like these, its is a good way?

```
const info = _.map(info.core, function (value: any) {
  const fields = _.map(value.fields, function (fields: any) {
    return field;
  });

  const demo = {
    name: name,
    fields: fields.join('')
  };

  return demo;
});

console.log(demo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you even need to map,.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

If you want to render this data, just parse it as is, you shouldn't need any more transformations.

Below I've used document.write just for simplicity, but a better way would be to manipulate the DOM directly with createElement etc.

```js
var info = {
    "core": [{
        "name": "User",
        "fields": [{
            "field": "name",
        }, {
            "field": "age",
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Post",
        "fields": [{
            "field": "title",

        }, {
            "field": "body",
        }, {
            "field": "author",
        }]
    }]
}

var w = document.write.bind(document);

info.core.forEach((c,i) => { 
  w(`<p>${i+1}.</p>`);
  w('<ul>');
  w(`<li>${c.name}</li>`);
  w('<li>fields');
  w('<ul>');
  c.fields.forEach((f) => {
    w(`<li>${f.field}</li>`);
  });
  w('</ul>');
  w('</li>');
  w('</ul>');
});
```